# TeamCity : Release branch checkout rule for different environment against Perforce repository

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, perforce, continuous-deployment, nolio

We are working on CI project to auto build and deploy application, database (schema and data), autosys and etl components using TeamCity and Nolio.

We are using Perfoce and having below branch structure

**main.br** ==> for developer work

> - core
>
>   - application ==> for .Net and Java applications
>   - database    ==> for schema objects
>   - scripts     ==> for config files (e.g. .ini, .bat)
> - branchX
>
>   - autosys     ==> for jil file
>   - etl         ==> for workflow
>   - data_sql    ==> for data sql script

**releases** ==> for release

> - Build
>
>   - tranche_1.0
>
>     - core     ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>     - branchX  ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>   - tranche_2.0
>
>     - core     ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>     - branchX  ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
> - SIT
>
>   - tranche_1.0
>
>     - core     ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>     - branchX  ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>   - tranche_2.0
>
>     - core     ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
>     - branchX  ==> with all subfolder as per main.br
> - UAT ==> same as DEV structure
> - PROD ==> same as DEV structure

We have setup releases branch as VCS root in TeamCity.

**Queries:**

```
- how to structure TeamCity jobs for different environment and tranche release.
- how to define check-out rule for different environment and tranche release.
```

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

For each type have seperate build configuration eg .NetProj1, Serviceproj2,Autosys1
Have neviornment set as Paramater eg Build.ENV = DEV 
Change this to QA or PROD before running build

Comment: Could you explain that in a bit more detail?